# SQL Query on XML Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server , I am trying to query on XML Column (i.e XmlPayload) with where clause.

My XML looks like this :-

```
<document>
  <AccountId>206221</AccountId>
  <AccountReference>OO1111928</AccountReference>
  <PolicyReference>OO1111928</PolicyReference>
   <Many other attributes...>
</document>
```

This is what I have tried , Its giving me an error message -

> XQuery [dbo.Bil_PaymentSearch.XmlPayload.value()]: Syntax error near
> ')', expected a step expression.

```
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[PaymentSearch]
    WHERE  XmlPayload.value('(/AccountReference/)[1]','nvarchar(20)') IN('OO1111928') 
    order by [PostingDate] ASC
```

Comment: try this once `XmlPayload.value('(document/AccountReference)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') IN ('OO1111928')`

Comment: Thank you so Much Sowmyadhar , Its working now.